# How to prevent Magento 2 from changing file permissions?

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

We are working on local environments to do our developments and we don't want Magento 2 to change file permissions - actually, we think that Magento 2 should never change file permissions, it's not its responsibility to handle filesystem strategy.

How can we do that? Currently, Magento 2 keeps on updating file ownership and permissions.

Comment: where is magento changing you file permissions?

Comment: Anytime we execute a command using bin/magento. For example, bin/magento setup:di:compile.

Comment: You need to execute them with your webserver user

Answer (score 0):

Magento is using the user configured in your web server (Nginx, Apache) and when executing Magento command you should also use this user.

For local development systems, it's fine IMHO to use the logged-in user.

For non-local systems you want to use a dedicated user (www-data) which is also supposed to run the cronjobs.